# What's the best way to receive ether payments in rails?

Tags: blockchain, ether, ruby, rails

I'm new to the field, I usually work with [Stripe on Rails](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails) to get traditional payments. Do you have some advice to get paid with Ether crypto coins on Rails ?

Which online merchant services or Ruby libraries can you suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of payment gateways that work with cryptocoins, [bitpay](https://bitpay.com/) and [gocoin](https://www.gocoin.com/) being examples I'm aware of. Just googled 'ether payment gateway' and found [coinpayments](https://www.coinpayments.net/) as well.

If you build it yourself you have to run a node, tie your business transaction to an expectation on the blockchain, wait for that expectation to be validated by the number of nodes you feel comfortable with, and then complete the transaction in your ruby app.

Comment: Why would you have to run a full node? Your app just has to be able to generate addresses to get paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Ruby library in Rails that allows you to manage accounts and query balances. I have recently published the [`eth`](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb) gem.

To create an account and get an address:

```ruby
user_key = Eth::Key.new
# < make your persistent, redundant backup here >
user_key.address.to_s
```

To check the balance, you can connect to a client:

```ruby
endpoint = Eth::Client.create "https://example.com:8545"
endpoint.get_balance user_key.address
```

If you prefer to manage the accounts externally or offline *(recommended)*, you can also just handle the user's payment addresses without any private key information, e.g.:

```ruby
user_address = Eth::Address.new "0x0c53ffa57ec554451315c2568d22477db8e71356"
endpoint.get_balance user_address
```